# Semantic UI items stacking instead of being spread across row

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic UI with rails and trying to have 4 items spread across a row but instead they are stacking vertically on top  of each other.

[image]

```
    <div class="ui four column grid">
        <div class="row">
          <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <div class="column">
              <div class="ui card">
                 <div class="image"><%= link_to (image_tag avatar.post, post_path(post), class: "ui tiny circular centered image"  %>
                 </div>

            <div class="content">
             <a class="header"><%= post.instagram_username %></a>
             <div class="extra content">
             <p><small><%= raw post.tags.map(&:name).map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t),class: "ui primary basic mini button" }.join %></small</p></div>
             </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you any CSS to show?

Comment: @ultrarun i'm using the default CSS for semantic, i haven't added any custom CSS

Comment: Please look over your HTML tags and properly close them all: the `small` tag is not really closed, and your `div` tags do not match.

Comment: Alos have you considered using `class="ui four cards"` instead of a grid?  [Docs](https://semantic-ui.com/views/card.html#column-count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this:

```
<div class="ui grid">
    <div class="row">
      <% @posts.each do |post| %>
       <div class="four wide column">
         <div class="column">
           <div class="ui card">
              <div class="image"><%= link_to (image_tag avatar.post, post_path(post), class: "ui tiny circular centered image"  %>
              </div>

         <div class="content">
          <a class="header"><%= post.instagram_username %></a>
          <div class="extra content">
          <p><small><%= raw post.tags.map(&:name).map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t),class: "ui primary basic mini button" }.join %></small</p></div>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
 </div>
```

Here you can find more [detail](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html)

OR

Just to make sure use this, should be horizontal.

```
<div class="ui grid"> 
 <div class="four wide column"></div> 
 <div class="four wide column"></div> 
 <div class="four wide column"></div> 
 <div class="four wide column"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I've just tried this but the items are still stacked on top of each other

Comment: Debug it by commenting the whole div after the class "four wide column" to make sure that other divs are not making any mess.
if it doesn't work then comment the row class. Let me know after this :)

Comment: I have updated my above answer with sample structure.

Comment: i re-did everything with the format you provided, turns out there was an extra closing div i had added that was messing everything up. thanks for the help